# Setter method for slice struct in golang

Tags: go, struct

I have an strut defined as below

```
type ReqJSON struct {
    Request struct {
        Data struct {
            Object struct {
                User []User `json:"user"`
            } `json:"object"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"request"`
}

type User struct {
    UserID string `json:"userid"`
    IPAddr string `json:"ipaddr"`
    Noofusers string `json:"noofusers"`
    Qos string `json:"qos"`
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Domain string `json:"domain"`
}
```

The setter function for this struct is as below

```
func (j *ReqJSON) User() User     { return j.Request.Data.Object.User } 
func (j *ReqJSON) SetUser(u User) { j.Request.Data.Object.User = u }
```

The main program is as follows

```
func main() {
    var j ReqJSON
    j.SetUser(User{
            UserID:    "_id",
            IPAddr:    "1.1.1.1",
            Noofusers: "100",
            Qos:       "34",
            ID:        "kldjflkdfjlkdjfkld",
            Domain:    "xyz.com",
    })

    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(j, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(err, string(b))
}
```

When I tried to make `User` as slice I am getting error for the above function.

> prog.go:27:65: cannot use j.Request.Data.Object.User (type []User) as
>   type User in return argument prog.go:28:64: cannot use u (type User)
>   as type []User in assignment

I am novice to Golang so not able to figure out how I can make Setter and Ctor to return slice object.

Comment: Show the code for "make User as a slice".

Comment: Show the code that is failing and also provide the error that you're getting.

Comment: I pasted it in goplayground and did not get any error: https://play.golang.org/p/VvuwHJShXBw What error do you see?

Comment: If you run with updated struct it will report error

Comment: @Abhinav you were not passing the slice of Users to the setter function which is why the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the single embedded user struct to a list of users you need to change it everywhere. Golang is strongly typed and a slice of users is a different type from a single user struct. The following code works

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type ReqJSON struct {
    Request struct {
        Data struct {
            Object struct {
                User []User `json:"user"`
            } `json:"object"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"request"`
}

type User struct {
    UserID    string `json:"userid"`
    IPAddr    string `json:"ipaddr"`
    Noofusers string `json:"noofusers"`
    Qos       string `json:"qos"`
    ID        string `json:"id"`
    Domain    string `json:"domain"`
}

func (j *ReqJSON) User() []User     { return j.Request.Data.Object.User } 
func (j *ReqJSON) SetUsers(u []User) { j.Request.Data.Object.User = u }

func main() {

    var j ReqJSON
    j.SetUsers([]User{
    User{
        UserID:    "_id",
        IPAddr:    "1.1.1.1",
        Noofusers: "100",
        Qos:       "34",
        ID:        "kldjflkdfjlkdjfkld",
        Domain:    "xyz.com",
    },
    })

    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(j, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(err, string(b))
}
```

Comment: There is nothing related to Go is strongly typed or not in OP question. The issue is OP is not passing slice of user in the setter function.

Comment: If this was python or any other dynamically typed language, passing a list of users instead of a single user to the same implementation would work just fine. But with go, you have to specify argument and return types for everything. Thats why I mentioned typing.

Comment: Well there is a big difference between a struct and an array of struct in any language.

Comment: Not true. As long as I am not trying to do something that is specific to the data structure (i.e. refer to an element by index on something that is not an array or referring to a member by name on something that is not a struct) a dynamic language doesn't care. If I were to turn a data structure into json in python, I would use `json.dumps(myobj)` and never have to specify what exactly myobj is, as long as it is something that is serializable. In go, you have to specify the type for everything.

Comment: I do not know that much about python but you are wrong here you cannot assign a primary type value to a variable which takes an array.

Comment: In a dynamically typed language you can. In a statically typed language you cannot. In python, ruby javascript you can do `x = 10` and in the next line `x = [10]` and it will work. In C++, Go, Java, Rust etc. you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing an error because `ReqJSON` struct contains a field for `User` which is a slice of `User` struct but when you are setting the Value for `User` struct you are not passing slice of User struct inside setter function.

```
type ReqJSON struct {
    Request struct {
        Data struct {
            Object struct {
                User []User `json:"user"` // this is a slice of User struct
            } `json:"object"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"request"`
}
```

You need to pass a slice of User struct in Setter function if you want to initialize the field inside `ReqJSON` struct which contains slice of `User` not `User`. Pass slice of User struct inside main as:

```
var u []User
u = append(u, User{
    UserID:    "_id",
    IPAddr:    "1.1.1.1",
    Noofusers: "100",
    Qos:       "34",
    ID:        "kldjflkdfjlkdjfkld",
    Domain:    "xyz.com",
})
j.SetUser(u)
```

Working Code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kJ24CrJRNdk)